# Can I use function in variable declaration in C? int f(), i;

Tags: c

From *Understanding Unix Programming*, chapter 1.6, `more01.c` example:

```
int see_more(), reply;
```

I [tried](http://ideone.com/c30yP6) some similar code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int hey(), reply;
    return 0;
}

int hey()
{
    printf("Hello");
};
```

No error in log, but no `Hello` on console. Can anybody explain this?

Comment: Did you try to put a protoype after your include ? int hey();

Comment: This is incorrect or at least very unusual C syntax. I wouldn't rely on whatever the compiler decides to do with it.

Comment: @Tobia Just because you have never seen it does not imply that the C standard does not unambiguously define what it means.

Comment: @PascalCuoq very well, so where does it allow function prototypes to be declared inside a function body and intermingled with variable declarations?

Comment: @Tobia C99TC3 6.8.2 and 6.7:1 are relevant. Make it a question if you want to see someone give more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will compile just fine. But all you're doing is *declaring* the function. This is the same as adding a (non-prototype) declaration at the top level.

```
int hey( );
//      ^ empty parens means it's not a prototype
```

You can call a function in a declaration if it's part of the initializer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int reply=hey();
    //        ^ here the function is called, even though this is a declaration,
    //          because the value is needed.
    return 0;
}
int hey(){
    return printf("Hello");
    // a function returning `int` ought to `return ` an int!
};
```

But normally to call a function you just place the call in a (non-declaration) expression statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int reply; // declaring a variable
    int hey(); // declaring a function
    (void) hey();     // function call, casting return value to (void)
    return 0;
}
int hey(){
    return printf("Hello");
};
```

---

There is a restriction in some earlier compilers that only the last declaration can contain a function call. C99 (and most "modern" compilers) have relaxed this restriction and function calls can now be used in initializers with impunity.

IIRC `splint` the syntax-checker has this same restriction on function calls in initializers.

---

It may be considered *bad style*, but it's not necessarily incorrect to call a function without a prototype. To be sure, it removes the compiler's ability to check that the call make sense from a type point-of-view. But all you really have to do is *don't screw it up*.

Non-prototyped functions will default to the standard calling conventions, which means all integer args (char, short, int) promote to `int` and all float args promote to `double`. These promotions also apply to variadic functions using `#include <stdarg.h>` (and our beloved `printf`), so I consider it very useful to know how a non-prototyped function will be called.

I've got some "don't screw it up" code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14868282/733077) that calls non-prototyped functions through a function-pointer. It all works and conforms to the standard (near as I can figure), but I have no idea how to prototype that function-pointer which may point to one of many stereotypical patterns. It wouldn't be correct to use a variadic notation `(...)`, because it's not the same thing. There's just no appropriate way to prototype it, so the pointer is just declared `void (*fp)();`.

Comment: where's the prototype ? user2822466 seems to be new to C, so he may not have understood why hey() is never called.

Answer (score 1):

you are just declaring the function there, not calling it.

Like this:

```
int main()
{
  extern int hey(); // there is a function "hey" somewhere

  hey();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`int hey()` method doesn't return any value. Try making it `void hey()`.

Comment: That's true (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079089/implicit-int-return-value-of-c-function), but it's not related to the question since the function is never called.